# how can we click on webpage from java code without using selenium?

Tags: javascript, java

Hi i want to get access token from an API after doing the google sign in. But i need to click on the Accept button from browser and get the Access token manually.

Can anyone suggest some method so that I can do Google sign-in and then click on accept button of the following screen and get the Access tokenthrough java code without using browser manually. I don't want to use selenium in production.

Comment: why would you want to do something like this in production?

Comment: @Stultuske I need to get Authentication token from Google every time i hit the API of our client in Production code.  i need to do it on daily basis because my module is to get the data from clients on daily basis and save that into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to automate logging-in via the UI to get Google sign-in working. Take a look at the [Java API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/), specifically the section on [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)  for how to authenticate from Java.

Note that the specifics are dependent on where you are signing-in from (is this happening on a server? in an Android app? a desktop app?) and whether you are trying to authenticate on behalf of a user or your app. Giving a little more detail/context here would help in recommending a specific utility or flow.

Comment: I have to do this sign in on windows server, where I am currently using selenium in production for opening the mozilla browser which on code execution does the google sign in and in next screen after the sign in, it clicks on the Accept button. After this process Access token comes on the Address bar of the browser.

If I had to do only the sign in then I can easily do this via tha java code but in this case after the sign in I need to click on the Accept button too in the following screen, this is creating the problem.

Comment: @LokeshNandanwar can you explain what you are doing with this? It sounds like you are having a server authenticate as if it were an end user. Either the user should be authenticating on their own device (and clicking the accept button, themselves), after which your service stores a refresh token, or you should be using a service account to allow your app to authenticate against an API (rather than authenticating as an ordinary user using the regular sign-in UI).

Comment: I (My code) am the user here, I have been provided client id and client secret by my client company to access their API via OAuth. so I have to get the access token by using the client id and client secret then using that access token I access my client API and get the data which i want to use  in my rest of the code. But I am facing issue in getting the Access token from the java code without using selenium

Comment: @LokeshNandanwar if you are truly trying to authenticate as yourself (rather than as your application, in which case you should be using a service account), then you should do this sign-in in an interactive context (like on a web page or mobile application), and then have this interactive application store the refresh token that is given on successful sign-in in a database. This refresh token in your database should then be used for subsequently requesting an auth token in your production context, rather than emulating a browser login.